# Uniform convergence of subsequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(f_{n})$ be a bounded sequence in $C[0,1]$ and let $g_{n}$ : $\mathbb{[0,1]} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a defined by $$g_{n}(x)=  {\int_{0}^x{f_{n}(t)}\mathrm dt}  $$
Prove that there is a subsequence of $(g_{n})$ which converges uniformly to a continuous function on $[0,1]$.
I had some trouble trying to solving this problem, I couldn't use the boundedness and also I couldn't pass to subsequence of g. Thanks!

Comment: This question could be interesting if you gave some indication of what you know about convergence in $C[0,1]$ or some indication of what you've tried and what the difficulty was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $\{g_{n}\}$ is uniformly bounded: $|g_{n}(x)|\leq\sup_{n}\|f_{n}\|_{\infty}|x|\leq\sup_{n}\|f_{n}\|_{\infty}$.

The $\{g_{n}\}$ is equicontinuous: For $x>y$, $|g_{n}(x)-g_{n}(y)|\leq\displaystyle\int_{y}^{x}|f_{n}(t)|dt\leq\sup_{n}\|f_{n}\|_{\infty}|x-y|$.

Then Arzela-Ascoli Theorem finishes the job. Note that $g_{n}$ are AC.